# StatusField not working with CreateAPIView

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-rest-framework

Here is a stripped down version of my situation:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils import Choices
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from model_utils.fields import StatusField
...
class Unit(models.Model):
    STATUS = Choices(
        (0, 'new', _('unit is new')),
        (1, 'refurb', _('unit is refurbished')),
        (2, 'scrap', _('unit is scrap')),
    )
    unit_type = StatusField(_('unit type'), default=STATUS.new)
    ...
```

views.py

```
class UnitCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Unit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UnitSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = super(UnitCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
```

serializers.py

```
class UnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = (..., 'unit_type', ...)
```

I use the post through a browsable api. It presents me with a form where I can select the 'new' option in the `STATUS` attribute in a dropdown. After the post is sent off, I find that the `resp` object has a 400 bad request error.

Upon investigation in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> resp.data
{'unit_type': ["Value '0' is not a valid choice."]}
```

So it seems like UnitCreateView is not playing well with StatusField, or else maybe serialization is causing a problem. Is there something obviously wrong with the code I've included here?

Comment: I replicated your case and it seems to work fine, no 400.. can I see the whole model definition? which version of django and drf are you using?

Comment: @mariodev Thanks for looking into it. (Note I did find a workaround below.)  Here's the version data though: python 3.4, django 1.7.7, djangorestframework 2.4.4, django-model-utils 2.1.1.   I think that's a complete cast of characters.

Comment: @mariodev Given the workaround, it seems like the other parts of the model were not involved in the problem.

Comment: UGH. With the fix below, the unit_type field disappears from the browsable API post form. I suppose I can still post the data to the endnpoint and things will work, but it looks like it crippled the browsable api tool for this endpoint.

Comment: Do you get 400 for any other selected value as well?

Comment: @mariodev Yes. Similar message. Another update: using the browsable api's raw_data field, I was able to add in the missing field into the json and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
unit_type = models.IntegerField(_('unit type'), choices=STATUS, default=STATUS.new)
```

Comment: Well sure, you can always abandon code for more elementary code, but as the title says, I'm trying to get StatusField to play well with CreateAPIView. I guess it might be time for a github issue.

Comment: I took this solution for a test drive today and got this error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "unit_type" cannot be cast automatically to type integer`  Perhaps more than just this one change is needed...

Comment: Oh yes I think that's the problem, since `StatusField` is a char type field and you're using integers (0,1,2) - hence the error `Value '0' is not a valid choice.` Try using text instead and see what happens..